# Change the div position with CSS on hover

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to change the positions of 2 div's when hover over a div. In the following code, when I hover over the .img div, I want to move the .title div at top (position for example top: 50px), and display the .info div below it which is initially set as hidden.

I am trying following code, but does not seem to work on hover. I will appreciate any help.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="img"><img src="http://i281.photobucket.com/albums/kk240/leahhaudrey/bubbles.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam imperdiet velit nec turpis tempus vehicula. Integer congue feugiat eros ac interdum. </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
img{
    display: block;
}

.title,
.info{
    background: white;
}

.box{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.title{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
}

.info{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
}

.img{
    background: red;
}

.img:hover{
    opacity: 0.4;    
}

.img:hover .info{
    display: block;
}
```

**Demo.**
http://jsfiddle.net/UPwv3/

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/UPwv3/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to change position of `.title`:

```
.box:hover .title {
    bottom: auto;
    top: 10px;
}
```

And this to turn visible hidden `.info` box:

```
.box:hover .info {
    display: block;
}
```

Here is result: http://jsfiddle.net/UPwv3/8/

Comment: Thank you very much. However when you hover the image and move your cursor on the title or the description, the background opacity effects disppears, could you please check that. I will highly appreciate.

Comment: @user2738640 make it triggered when the `.box` is hovered instead. `.box:hover .img{
    opacity: 0.4;    
}`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UPwv3/12/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `adjacent sibling selector`

```
.img:hover + .title {
    bottom: 50px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UPwv3/9/)

This will move an element having `.title` which is adjacent to `.img` on hovering element having `.img`

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code

```
.img:hover ~ .info{
    display: block;

}
.box:hover .title {
    bottom: auto;
    top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make your class

```
.img:hover .info{
    display: block;
}
```

work, 'info' should be a nested element of 'image'. Have a look at the following fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/pY9jx/3/